# Output following entry of an array with every call of a function (and loop around)

Tags: javascript

I´m trying to write a function that outputs one of 16 numbers, following each other every time the function gets called.

I have an array with 16 numbers, so if the function gets called for the first time it should output 1, the second time 2 until we reach 16, then it should loop around and output 1 ... 16 again.

Comment: Have you tried something yourself?  Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Hello there is more than one solution. You can use generators for it [DOC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators).

```js
function* gen() {
 const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16];
  let index = 0;
  while(true) {
   yield arr[index++ % arr.length];
  }
}

const generator = gen();
for(let i = 0; i < 150; i++) {
 console.log(generator.next().value);
}
```

Another possible solution is function inside function.

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16];
function generate() {
 let index = 0;
 return function() {
   return arr[index++ % arr.length];
  }
}

const generator = generate();
for(let i = 0; i < 150; i++) {
 console.log(generator());
}
```

Comment: thanks everyone, i will try all suggestions!
this is not ment for a website but to be used within MAX, a graphical programming environment that supports javascript from cycling74.com.